# IOS not receiving GCM push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a project build by swift in xcode 7 and i apply gcm to my project. I just received data from gcm but not showing alert notification in my ios devices. [My AppDelegate](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyckrayl4pnau4b/AppDelegate.swift?dl=0)

Comment: Please include the code in the question.

Comment: I use code following this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift . My code in here https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyckrayl4pnau4b/AppDelegate.swift?dl=0

Comment: If you'r running using Xcode  it will be the dev build, so make sure you are using the dev certificates and GMC dev environment else it won't work.

Comment: i've received message in console but device not showing dialog notification.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered something similar. The reason mine wasn't working was because of the `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption` value. I had to set it to `true` for debug builds and `false` for distribution builds.

Answer (score 1):

You're posting an NSNotificationCenter type of notification, thats not something the user sees, its not an alert notification which the user can see. You want UILocalNotification